# How to know when mouse leaves my window when WM_MOUSELEAVE sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent

I'm having a problem with `TrackMouseEvent` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.  I call `TrackMouseEvent` in my app when the mouse is over my window in the `WM_SETCURSOR` and `WM_NCHITTEST` handlers.  The problem is that if I move the mouse very quickly out of my window, I don't get `WM_MOUSELEAVE` at all.

I'm fairly sure I'm using this correctly, because normal, slower movements will produce `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.  It's only when the mouse is moving too fast that it doesn't get generated.  The problem is, how am I supposed to detect this?  My app isn't always in the foreground, so I'm not sure `SetCapture` will do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that WM_NCMOUSELEAVE is what you need.

Edit: It's worth mentioning in my opinion that the docs imply that you must call TrackMouseEvent. However, I never did this and I still got the MOUSELEAVE message. Perhaps this call is now redundant and/or buggy?

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that TrackMouseEvent is not reliable.  When I've needed reliable mouse leaves, I've used timers instead.  (apologies for cutting this from an MFC project)

```
void OnNotifyMouseLeave()
{
    // Mouse is gone
}

void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    if ( m_uTimerId == 0 )
        m_uTimerId = SetTimer( MOUSELEAVE, 250, NULL );

    ...
}

void OnTimer( UINT_PTR nIDEvent ) 
{
    if ( nIDEvent == MOUSELEAVE )
    {
        POINT pt;
        RECT rect;
        GetCursorPos( &pt );
        GetWindowRect( &rect );
        if ( !PtInRect( &rect, pt ) )
        {   OnNotifyMouseLeave();
            if ( m_uTimerId != 0 )
            {   KillTimer( m_uTimerId );
                m_uTimerId = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I like that. It's nice, but it leaves you with a timer going off all the time. More reliable though. Wonder if it would be less overhead to have OnMouseMove kill if existing timer and start a new one, so you don't have purposeless timers going off while you know the user is moving across the field.

Comment: Well, the timer is killed if the user moves the mouse out of the window.  And while the mouse is in the window, there is only four calls per second.  That should be fairly low overhead.

Answer (score 0):

MouseLeave is finicky. SetCapture is what you need to use. Besides I don't think you can get mouse messages reliably if your app isn't in focus.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid using SetCapture since TrackMouseEvent sounded like it would do what I wanted, and with less work.  I guess I'll switch to SetCapture and see if that works better.